# Nginx PPA with Google PageSpeed

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm looking for a PPA for Nginx with Google's PageSpeed module installed. Haven't been able to successfully pull off a proper install for the last day.

Any suggestions on the best PPA to use for this?

I know Easyengine had one, but it looks like they took it out in Ver 3.6 not sure why.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I guess that they took it out because http2 was broken in combination with pagespeed, and it slowed down actually, now there came out a patch to fix that. so now probably it is ok, maybe with patch I don't know yet. I want to compile it too.

Answer (score 0):

I compile ngx_pagespeed.so dynamically on ubuntu server 16.04, you can load it when you need. I put it on Github: https://github.com/breeze2/ngx_pagespeed.so